# Why can this form be submitted? (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox, onsubmit

I have a very strange error in Firefox (Version 38.05). I have a form that looks like the following, and a Javascript snipped for validation

```
<form action='#' onsubmit='return check()'>
    <input type='text' name='asdf'/>
    <input type='submit' name='jkl' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function check(){
    alert("asdf");
    return false;
}
```

Now this form should never be submitted. But in Firefox it can be submitted without disabling Javascript if you follow this procedure:

1. Click submit
2. Confirm the Alert dialog
3. Click submit again
4. Check the box to prevent further Alert windows and click OK
5. Click submit --> the form will be submitted

Is this a Bug or a feature? In Chrome everything works fine. If this behaviour is intended, how can i avoid it?

Comment: it's not a bug it's a feature

Comment: Due to the presence of an `alert` and the historic wackiness of it, I suppose it's a good old bug. A snippet could help!

Comment: just avoid using `alert` and use `console.log`

Comment: `console.log` is not an option. This is supposed to be a message to the user who fills out the form

Comment: @chillichief I've just updated my answer to help you to display a custom alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what happens is that when `alert()` is invoked while blocked by the user, Firefox and Chrome have different behaviours!

While Chrome simply fails silently, trying to `alert` in Firefox when it's been blocked by the user throws an Exception. And `onSubmit` handlers are only blocked if the function explicitly returns false.

A somewhat dirty fix would be:

```
function check() {
  try {
    alert('foo');
  }
  catch {
    //User prevented alerts, fallback
    showSomehow('foo'); //use a log, a div on the top of the page, ...
  }
  return false;
}
```

One would need to have more motivation than me and delve into the deepness of the specs to know who's right on that.

Comment: as he said in comments `console.log is not an option. This is supposed to be a message to the user who fills out the form –  `

Comment: @Magicprog.fr Well yeah, but when the `alert` can't be done anymore, you've got to fallback on something else. Let me make this clear.

Comment: @Magicprog.fr, nope, the question is "why can this form be submitted", not "how to display an alert when user has blocked the standard one".

Comment: @Pavlo Well, the title is this, yes, but what about `If this behaviour is intended, how can i avoid it?`

Comment: Let it be clear: If the user does not want to be `alert`ed, you're not going to be able to call `alert()`. End of the line. You can use modals, logs, redirections or trollfaces, but you're not going to use `alert()`.

Comment: This was exactly what im looking for. THX. Alert will not be called, but the form cant be submitted either until fully validated. Very nice explenation on how FF handles Alerts.

Answer (score -1):

preventing alert windows in ff causing js errors and sometimes js stop working at all after that, so your `return false;` is not executed
try something like

```js
function check(event){
    event = window.event || event;
    event.preventDefault(); 
    alert("asdf");
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form action='#' onsubmit='check(event)'>
    <input type='text' name='asdf'/>
    <input type='submit' name='jkl' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a console.log will work each time, but alert can be blocked, and the function will not be called.

You can display your own custom alert if you need to.

You should probably move your event handler from inline:

HTML:

```
<form action='#' id="my-form">
    <input type='text' name='asdf'/>
    <input type='submit' name='jkl' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = function() {
    console.log("asdf");
    return false;
}
```

Firefox `remove` the function containing the `alert` so you need to move the `alert out of your function`:

**This will allow you to return false, even if the alert is disabled !**

```
document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = function() {
    console.log("asdf");
    displayAlert();
    return false;
}
function displayAlert() {
    alert("test");    
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/nddtf13q/

**To display a custom alert:**

This code will display a custom alertbox, which can't be blocked by firefox using a div. You should do some CSS to make it like you want it, but the main idea is here:

HTML:

```
<form action='#' id="my-form">
    <input type='text' name='asdf' />
    <input type='submit' name='jkl' value='Submit' />
</form>
<div id="alertBox">
    <div id="alertContent">asdf</div>
    <button id="alertOK">OK</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#alertBox {
    display:none;
    background: grey none repeat scroll 0 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -275px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 550px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = function () {
    displayAlert("asdf");
    return false;
}
function displayAlert(msg) {
    document.getElementById('alertContent').innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById('alertBox').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('alertOK').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('alertBox').style.display = "none";
    };
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/dkruqsqv/

Comment: "This will allow you to return false, even if the alert is disabled !" Actually no. In your setup `displayAlert` will throw an Exception on Firefox if `alert()` has been disabled and the anonymous handler will stop its execution.

Comment: You could change it to `setTimeout(displayAlert, 0)` to execute it after the `onSubmit` handler has returned though.